# What are the biggest difference between react native and flutter?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app

Now a days most developer are using cross platform app development frameworks for build to various mobile apps.I am still beginner for the react native app development.But I have heard flutter is the best more than react native.Is it true? if is it true, please tell me what are the biggest difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

- react depend on javascript language
- flutter on dart language
- react is a framework of js
- Flutter is not just a framework but a complete SDK
- react work on the web as react js and on mobile as react-native.
- dart is oop language work on the web with the compiler to js and flutter as mobile development.
- Using the Dart language allows Flutter to compile the source code ahead-of-time to native code.
- react Instead of compiling down to native code, React Native takes your application and runs it using the host platform's JavaScript engine, without blocking the main UI thread. You get the benefits of native performance, animations, and behavior, without having to write Objective-C or Java.
  -